# Battery showing 100% charged with ''Consider changing your battery''

Tags: battery

Is it normal to have a laptop have the warning ''Consider changing your battery'' but whilst also showing 100% charged. I've got the red cross on the charge symbol showing with Windows 7 on my Acer Aspire One D270. Any things for me to try? Should i let the battery completely discharge or keep the charger plugged in? Thanks

Comment: Unplug the machine, use it until there is a noticeable drop in power on the battery. Then plug it in and see if that help. I suspect the battery is failing but .....

Answer (score 0):

Discharge your battery until your laptop gets shut down after that charge your battery full then turn on your laptop. The problem will be sorted out. If problem still persists check your battery.

[Check your battery](http://bestthings4u.blogspot.in/2012/12/check-your-battery-health-in-laptop.html) status by using **powercfg -Energy** command with administrator privilege.

Answer (score 0):

Modern battery systems recalibrate themselves so that 100% should always be 100% of what your battery is capable of storing *given its age and wear*. So if you see 100% but also a "consider changing your battery" message, it could mean that your battery is near the end of its life, and is only capable of storing, say, half the energy it was able to store when it was new.

Lithium-Ion (Li-ion) batteries, including Lithium-Polymer (LiPo), tend to lose a significant amount of their capacity after 300 to 400 charge-discharge cycles. So if you fully discharge your laptop every day, and fully charge it back up every night, your battery might only last 1 year before you notice enough performance degradation that you'd prefer to buy a new battery. If you only halfway drain it and charge it each day, it might only last 2 years.

Of course, as with all things high-tech, you could be hitting a bug. If your battery is well under a year old, and it still seems to last just as long on a charge as it ever did, then you're probably hitting a bug. Many battery systems don't fully recalibrate themselves unless you fully charge the battery then fully discharge it (without partially recharging it along the way), and then fully charge it again (without partially draining it along the way). So you could try doing that. However, that recalibration cycle is usually what's needed if the battery never shows 100%; it's the way for the battery monitoring system to learn just how warn-out your battery is, so it can readjust what level it considers "100%". I doubt this recalibration cycle with help in your case. You may very well just be due for a new battery.